# How to set device ringtone in android?

Tags: android

I am developing VOIP calling app in android.

I want the app ringtone to be the same as device default ringtone, when I receive a call from another user on this app. Can someone please tell me how I can achieve this?

Comment: is it helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29256684/android-ringtone-set-programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8568304/4180965)

Replace `RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION` with `RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE`.

Comment: I have use AudioManager instead of RingtoneManager

Comment: That should work yes

Comment: I have implemented your previous answer and That's worked ......Thank you Boss

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark as answer :)

Comment: I have one more question for you

Comment: I have a user name editText in which i want when user sign in to nextpage and in next page when user pressed back in android device he became signout what is the solution of when user press back he will stay on that page

Comment: That is a difference question. Please open another question for this. Thaks

Comment: @TejjD How to set ringtone to none(no ringtone) programmatically please help