# Set as ringtone / notification sound in java , android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ringtonemanager

I have been developing a soundboard app where my sounds(mp3) are stored in resources and the media player plays them using the tag of the same name on each button. For the life of me I cant get my head around how to set as notification and ringtone sound , ultimately from a longpress , any help would be extremely gratefully appreciated its driving me mad .

Thankyou

Comment: is this link your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40420969/set-a-sound-file-as-ringtone-and-notification-programmatically-in-android

Comment: Thankyou I will give it a go , much appreciated

Comment: If that is your answer tell me tnx.

Comment: Sure when I get around to get round to trying it I will let you know the outcome :) thanks again